# Different images size on page indicator

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve carousel page indicator that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to achieve this like set `selector` xml drawable in to `ImageView`s as follows:

`selector_carousel_page_indicator.xml` dwalable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" >
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/lightBlue" />
        <size android:width="5dp" android:height="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_selected="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
            <size android:width="8dp" android:height="8dp" />
        </shape>
</item>
```

Adding drawables for each page

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    ImageView obj = new ImageView(getContext());
    obj.setImageResource(R.drawable.selector_carousel_page_indicator);
    obj.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
    llPageIndicatorContainer.addView(obj);
    carouselPageIndicators.add(obj);
}
```

`llPageIndicatorContainer` is just a `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/PageIndicatorLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_below="@+id/ViewPagerCarousel"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/pageIndicatorMargin"
     android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

But the dots appears in the same size like the following.

Any ideas what can be wrong or how to achieve desired view?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a `<size>` tag to define the two different sizes, I would use an `<inset>` tag:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/lightBlue"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <inset
            android:insetRight="1.5dp"
            android:insetLeft="1.5dp"
            android:insetTop="1.5dp"
            android:insetBottom="1.5dp">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/gray"/>
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Then I would create a layout resource for your image instead of constructing it in Java, which allows you to define the size in the layout:

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_selector"/>
```

And then you can do the inflation basically the same way as before:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    View obj = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_indicator, llPageIndicatorContainer, false);
    llPageIndicatorContainer.addView(obj);
    carouselPageIndicators.add(obj);
}
```

[image]